# Cant send message trought when button pressed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, geolocation, adobe

Cant send message trought when button pressed

when it gets gps coordinates it sends email every time, but doesn't work on button click

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::MouseEvent@6d6a6d1 to flash.events.GeolocationEvent.

```
ve_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_UpdateGeolocation_2);

var fl_GeolocationDisplay_2:TextField = new TextField();
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.text = "Geolocation is not responding. Verify the device's    location settings.";
addChild(fl_GeolocationDisplay_2);

if(!Geolocation.isSupported)
{
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.text = "Geolocation is not supported on this device.";
}
else
{
var fl_Geolocation_2:Geolocation = new Geolocation();
fl_Geolocation_2.setRequestedUpdateInterval(1000);
fl_Geolocation_2.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, fl_UpdateGeolocation_2);
}

function fl_UpdateGeolocation_2(event:GeolocationEvent):void
{
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.text = "latitude: ";
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.appendText(event.latitude.toString() + "\n");
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.appendText("longitude: ");
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.appendText(event.longitude.toString() + "\n");
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.appendText("altitude: ");
fl_GeolocationDisplay_2.appendText(event.altitude.toString() + "\n");
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:test@test.lv?body=</br>  latitude=" +    event.latitude.toString() + "</br>  longitude=" + event.longitude.toString()));
}
```

Comment: the parameter event:MouseEvent in the ve(...) method does not have a property or method called GeolocationEvent, so you cannot write "event.GeolocationEvent()" because it doesn't exist.

Comment: I made some changes now it works
ve_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_UpdateGeolocation_2);

Comment: but the problem is when it gets coordinates it sends mail automaticly but i need it only on mouse click

Comment: look at this code now i made some changes...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use same event handler with different types of Event. While geolocation works with `GeolocationEvent`, you are trying to pass `MouseEvent` to the same event listener.

```
ve_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e: MouseEvent):void{
    //Get last location and mail it
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::MouseEvent@4fe86d1 to flash.events.GeolocationEvent.

Comment: maybe you have some briliant idea?

Comment: Because this is incorrect `ve_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_UpdateGeolocation_2)`